# Convert print function from Firefox Addon to WebExtension?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Firefox Addon with bellow funtions:

- Print a webpage from URL with same domain
- Print preview a webpage from URL with same domain
- Choose a printer in a list printer when print
- Allow input print options when print, ex: margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right, .....

Now I need covert it to WebExtension for run with new FireFox (version 60 or higher). Could you help me find extension API for above funtion

Answer (score 1):

The current API allows only to print and print preview tabs, without settings:

```
browser.tabs.print() // will print the current tab
browser.tabs.printPreview() // will print preview the current tab
```

An API with more options is being worked on, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1385827